# Add item to Model.List<item> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

My Model has fields which are displayed on the screen, as well as a List which is displayed in a grid on the screen. I have an Add button, which shows a modal popup (without a postback), that allows the user to enter a few fields, and then clicks 'Save'. At the moment, I use a JSON call back to my controller to save the data. I then reload the screen, and the new item appears in the grid, as it was saved to the database, and the Model reloaded.

Problem is, if the user has made any changes to the main details in the model, they're lost, because all the JSON call did was save a new item to the database, and redirect to the main screen which reloads.

What I need to rather do is somehow, add the new item from the popup, to the main Model, and then reload the grid, without saving to the database at all, and without a postback.

My javascript for posting the data from the view looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btnSubmitNewCard').click(function () {
            var data = { cardNumber: $('.txtNewCardNumber').val(), cardHolder: $('.txtNewCardHolder').val(), expiryMonth: $('.txtNewExpiryMonth').val(), expiryYear: $('.txtNewExpiryYear').val(), active: $('.txtNewActive').val(), accountId: $('.Id').val() };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SaveBankCard", "BankAccount")',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.Success == 'true') {
                        window.location = '@Url.Action("EditBankAccount", "BankAccount", new { bankAccountId = Model.Id })';
                        } else {
                            alert(result.Message);
                        }
                    },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Oh no");
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And then the controller method that handles this, looks like this:

```
public JsonResult SaveBankCard(string cardNumber, string cardHolder, int expiryMonth, int expiryYear, string active, int accountId)
{
    var card = new AccountCardDto
    {
        Id = 0,
        AccountId = accountId,
        Active = active == "on",
        CardHolderName = cardHolder,
        CardNumber = cardNumber,
        ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2000 + expiryYear, expiryMonth, 1)
    };

    var id = new BankAccountService().SaveCard(card);

    var result = new { Success = "true", Message = "Saved", NewId = id };
    var r = new JsonResult
    {
        Data = result
    };

    return r;
}
```

So, the data is saved in the controller, and then the Javascript redirects to roload the whole screen. Can this be changed to rather save the data to the models' List client side, and then the whole model with changes and additions get saved via the one Save button on my screen? Is it possible to add to the Model's List client side?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

try json script like this

```
$('#ddlCompany').change(function () {
            //var URL = $('#Enrollform').data('fetchproduct');
            $.getJSON('/EnrollmentForm/fetchproduct/' + $('#ddlCompany').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a Product</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, product) {
                    items += "<option value='" + product.Value + "'>" + product.Text + "_" + product.Value + "</option>";
                });
                $('#ddlProduct').html(items);
            });
        });
```